# dualhead nvidia twinview + one monitor rotated

Tags: x11, nvidia

So I have two monitors, I want to rotate one in portrait. AFAIK twinview doesn't allow single monitor rotation -- both monitors are rotated.

The reason I want twinview is because it allows compositing. My question would be, is there anything I can do to have compositing, dual head, and one of the monitors in portrait mode. If not, when are these ridiculously simple problems going to be addressed?

-- edit --

Just bought another high-spec monitor to go with my main one, no portrait for me. Going to get a neck injury with these 2 16:10 monitors.

Comment: Sadly, as far as I can tell, the hardware isn't cooperating. If you want to tune rotation, you pretty much have to forget acceleration.

Comment: I'm afraid you were going to say that. my concluding sentence was intentional, sorting out a simple linear transform in a GPU that has 528 processing cores is abysmally lazy on Nvidia's part, so I will roll it back:/

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked with the open source driver nouveau. It supports randr and you can arbitrarily rotate any of your screens independently of the remaining screens. So if your card is supported by the open source driver and you don't need the performance and/or features of the nvidia driver, you can use it.